# KVM Disk Image File Path openSUSE

Tags: networking, opensuse, kvm

I need to enable networking for my guest KVM Windows 10 VM under openSUSE Tumbleweed host. I need the default file path for the virtual disk image as per [here](http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/Networking). Running the following command:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -hda /path/to/hda.img
```

Linux has such a complex file tree, I'm a bit lost! I installed VM via Virtual Machine Manager 1.1.0.

EDIT: How do I enable networking? Am I right to run above command?

Comment: My guess is whoever downvoted that did so because the question could be a bit clearer. You can improve your question by providing specific version information and posting the language from the manual to which you are referring. Someone familiar with the system then might already know the answer. Hope this helps!

Comment: How did you create your image? Was it in `yast`, `virt-manager`, or something else?

Comment: `virt-manager` I believe.

Comment: Then you should probably refer to the documentation of `virt-manager` and not to the one of bare KVM/QEMU. You might even find the machine ready to be run with a couple of clicks if you use the tools as used for creating the image.

Comment: The machine runs but no networking. I have asked on SUSE forum.

Answer (score 0):

If it was virt-manager, it should be somewhere in /var/lib/libvirt/images/.
In case of Yast, I have no idea.
Anyway, I'd try following command:

```
find / -name 'hda.img'
```

substitute hda.img for the name of disk created.